# AppSync with AWS4 and mixed authentication type (UserPools and IAM)

Tags: aws-lambda, graphql, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, aws-appsync

I have an AppSync GraphQL API defined. The API is using Cognito UserPools as primary authentication. This part works fine.

I am trying to execute the request from the Nodejs Lambda function using `axios` and `aws4`. The mutation I am trying to hit is configure something like this in my schema (omitting most of the schema):

```
AppSyncSchema:
    Type: AWS::AppSync::GraphQLSchema
    Properties:
      ApiId: !GetAtt MyApi.ApiId
      Definition: |
        type Something {
          someId: ID!
        }
        input SomethingInput {
          someId: ID!
        }
        type Mutation {
          doSomething(input: SomethingInput!): Something @aws_iam
        }
```

I have configure the Lambda function execution role to have `appsync:GraphQL` permission:

```
"Action": [
  "appsync:GraphQL"
],
"Resource": "arn:aws:appsync:eu-west-2:xxxx:apis/yyyy/*",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Sid": "AllowAppSyncExecution"
```

From different articles online, I have put together some request that my Nodejs Typescript function then tries to execute:

```
 const doSomething = `mutation doSomething($input: SomethingInput!) {
    doSomething(input: $input) {
      someId
    }
  }`;

  const data = {
    operationName: 'doSomething',
    query: doSomething,
    variables: {
      input: { someId: 'abc' },
    },
  };
  const body = JSON.stringify(data);

  const signOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://zzzz.appsync-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/graphql, 
    host: 'zzzz.appsync-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com',
    path: '/graphql',
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
    service: 'appsync',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
    },
    body, // used by aws4
    data, // used by axios
  };

  const creds = {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    sessionToken: process.env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN,
  };

  const signed = aws4.sign(signOptions, creds);
  delete signed.headers.Host;
  delete signed.headers['Content-Length'];

  console.log(signed);
  console.log('Got signed headers');

  try {
    await axios(signed);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Fialed to execute AppSync request', err);
    throw err;
  }
```

I am always getting a `Request failed with status code 401` response back. The AppSync logs don't reveal much more:

```
{
    "logType": "RequestSummary",
    "requestId": "11111111",
    "graphQLAPIId": "some id",
    "statusCode": 401,
    "latency": 7079000
}
```

What am I missing in configuring this correctly? Is there something I need to add to allow AWS IAM only for a specific mutation or do you see any issue with the way I am trying to execute the request?

These are the articles I was referencing:

[manually-triggering-appsync-apollo-subscriptions](https://medium.com/@barend.bootha/manually-triggering-appsync-apollo-subscriptions-6e78471821ca)

[calling-amazon-api-gateway-authenticated-methods-with-axios-and-aws4](https://medium.com/@joshua.a.kahn/calling-amazon-api-gateway-authenticated-methods-with-axios-and-aws4-6eeda1aa8696)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it working. I had to add additional authentication provider to the `AWS::AppSync::GraphQLApi`. In CloudFormation, this looks like an additional property:

```
  Type: AWS::AppSync::GraphQLApi
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref MyApi
      AuthenticationType: AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS
      UserPoolConfig:
        UserPoolId: !Ref MyPool
        AwsRegion: !Ref MyRegion
        DefaultAction: ALLOW
      AdditionalAuthenticationProviders:
        - AuthenticationType: AWS_IAM
```

After making this work, I got a response from AppSync GraphQL but it contained GraphQL errors for all fields in the response object:

`Not Authorized to access someId on type Something`

To get around this I had to also allow IAM on this type in the GraphQL Schema:

```
type Something @aws_cognito_user_pools @aws_iam {
  someId: ID!
}
```